# Why does variable loss its value after end of block?

Tags: c

I have written a code to test a substring operation.

**test.c**

```
#include "compiler_expression.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *s1 = "(Hello) World";
    int l = 0;
    printf("%s\n", substr_limits(s1, '(', ')', &l));
    return 0;
}
```

**compiler_expression.h**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
// strcpy(s1, s2) Copies s2 into s1
// strcat(s1, s2) Concatenates s2 onto the end of s1
// strlen(s1) Returns the length of s1
// strcmp(s1, s2) Returns 0 if s1 and s2 are the same; less than 0 if s1<s2; greater 
// than 0 if s1>s2
// strchr(s1, ch) Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of ch in s1
// strstr(s1, s2) Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of s2 in s1

char * substr(char *str, int begin, int end)
{
    if (begin<0 || end>strlen(str))
    {
        printf("\nError: arguments (begin or end) is out of index\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *res = malloc(end-begin);
    for (int i=begin; i<end; i++)
    {
        res[i-begin] = str[i];
    }
    return res;
}
char *substr_limits(char *str, char begin_char, char end_char, int *no_limit)
{
    *no_limit = 1;
    if (begin_char==end_char)
    {
        printf("%s\n", "::begin char is equal to end char");
        int begin_limit = 0;
        int end_limit = 0;
        int limit_num = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", "::begin first loop");
            if (str[i]!=begin_char) continue;
            printf("%s\n", "::limit char found");
            if (limit_num==1)
            {
                printf("%s\n", "::limit_num==1");
                end_limit = i;
                char *res = malloc(end_limit-begin_limit-1);
                for (int j=begin_limit+1;j<end_limit;j++)
                {
                    printf("%s%c\n", "::char==", str[j]);
                    res[j-begin_limit] = str[j];
                    printf("%s%c\n", "::res_char==", res[j-begin_limit]);
                }
                printf("%s%s\n", "::result==", res);
                return res;
            }
            *no_limit = 0;
            limit_num = 1;
            begin_limit = i;
        }
        if (limit_num!=0) {
            printf("\nError: The limits are not justified\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (*no_limit==1) {
            return str;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int begin_limit = 0;
        int end_limit = 0;
        int limit_num = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
        {
            if (str[i]!=begin_char&&str[i]!=end_char) continue;
            *no_limit = 0;
            if (str[i]==begin_char)
            {
                limit_num += 1;
                if (limit_num==1) begin_limit = i;
            }
            else if (str[i]==end_char)
            {
                limit_num -= 1;
                if (limit_num==0)
                {
                    end_limit = i;
                    char *res = malloc(end_limit-begin_limit);
                    for (i=begin_limit+1;i<end_limit;i++)
                    {
                        res[i-begin_limit] = str[i];
                    }
                    return res;
                }
            }
        }
        if (limit_num!=0) {
            printf("\nError: The limits are not justified\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (*no_limit==1) {
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

at the function (substr_limits), there is a problem: when the condition (begin_char==end_char) is true and after executing all code, I noticed at last operations before executing (return res;) that the code is run in the correct way and get all specified characters from (str) into (res) variable but after ending block of (for loop), I have noticed that the value of (res) is blank string which makes also the returned value is blank string, I was trying to solve problem by writing this code:

```
            char *res = malloc(end_limit-begin_limit-1);
            for (int j=begin_limit+1;j<end_limit;j++)
            {
                printf("%s%c\n", "::char==", str[j]);
                res[j-begin_limit] = str[j];
                printf("%s%c\n", "::res_char==", res[j-begin_limit]);
                if (j==end_limit-1) {
                    printf("%s%s\n", "::result==", res);
                    return res;
                }
            }
```

But the problem still exists!

Comment: This isn't your issue, but don't put code in header files. But your string code in a separate `.c` file and have a `.h` file just to declare the public functions from .the `.c`

Comment: `oticed at last operations before executing (return res;) that the code is run in the correct way` - what is a "correct way" of running code? Please don't describe what happens. Please write a program, present it's output and what output you want to have and _show_ the difference. Well you do `limit_num = 1;` and `begin_limit = i;` then on the next loop you enter `if (limit_num==1)` with `end_limit = i;` - so the difference between `begin_limit - end_limit` is always going to be 1, ie. the returned string will always be empty. Are you missing a second loop? What should the `substr_limits` do?

Comment: When are you seeing unexpected values in `res`? After the `return`, there is no more variable `res` - or do you mean at the memory the returned pointer points at? It would help get a useful answer if you can remove irrelevant code: post something as small as possible that still has the problem behavior, per [mcve].

Comment: Also, exactly what is `substr_limits` expected to do?

Comment: I use substr_limits function to substring using characters instead of begin and end values, for example: {string}(string) or |string|

Comment: @AssemblyCoding - That doesn't make any sense what you just said.  Imagine if I `substr_limits` was in the standard C runtime and you looked it up on MSDN, Google, or just typed `man substr_limits` on a linux prompt.  How would the function get described in terms of what it does with the parameters and what it is supposed to return?  As you have explained it, you've got this weird function called `substr_limits` and no one knows what it is supposed to do.  We can't debug your program unless you can suggest one test case of input parameters and what the expected output is.

Comment: You continually use `%s` to print things that are not null-terminated strings

Answer (score 2):

Bug #1.  Instead of this:

```
char *res = malloc(end-begin);
for (int i=begin; i<end; i++)
{
    res[i-begin] = str[i];
}
```

This:

```
char *res = malloc(end-begin+1);  //+1 for null char
for (int i=begin; i<end; i++)
{
    res[i-begin] = str[i];
}
res[end-begin] = '\0'; // null terminate the string that gets returned
```

I don't see `substr` getting invoked, but I see other variations of this string copy pattern missing the null char in your limits function.

More to come as I keep looking at the code....